# looking for c++ library/tool for making a window and manipulating individual pixels through coordinates

Tags: linux, library, c++, gui

I am trying to find a c++ library/tool that will let me make a window and change pixel colors (preferably just from black to white), using coordinates, I have been looking, but ended up just going in circles, I am using linux with the kde desktop. the window would be purely an output, with inputs from execution on the cli. And I suppose that "pixels" would not be the right term, I want to have blocks in a window that I can assign a value to. Just making a grid in the cli to output white blocks of text to could also work, but I would prefer a window related solution

Thank you for your time.

-J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the proper library, its https://cimg.eu/index.html

Edit: it's the proper library because it supports changing color values on individual pixels using x and y values, which I am using to visualize equations of parabolas and lines. there are better ways to visualize equations, but this more fun because I wanted to perform the calculations myself.

Comment: Hi @setanta!  Would it be possible to expand on why this library is the best choice for your needs?  Maybe highlight some of its features and how well it's maintained?